# Logging: one Dump to rule them all?

Tags: c#, t-sql, sql-server-2008, logging, ssis

Logging is quite an important task in my current project: the only problem is, that there are many sources where smth can happen: There is a SQL-Server 2008 R2, WCF Services and WPF Clients.

On the Servers there are procedures running as jobs, SSIS-Jobs and calls from the EF.
The WCF-Services are IIS 7.5 hosted and the Client is a WPF Application.

My problem now is to find a way to log everything into one location (**except the Eventlog!**). The real problem here are of course the procedures which are running during the night. For the rest I could already think of ways to solve it.

Any Ideas how to do this in a proper way?

Comment: With the nightly procedures, I only mean the SQL-jobs: and those jobs are not performing SSIS-Packages, but procedures. For the SSIS-Packages there are several possibilities to write logs (again, except the eventlog...)

Answer (score 0):

you could use a sql trace.

see http://sqlserverpedia.com/wiki/Running_Traces_with_TSQL